# ajax refresh form content after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am building a page where you click a button and it loads the div using ajax (reduce load time, and keep them on the same page). When you click the button to load the div with the form it loads the form as expected. I am trying to get it to reload the form once a user clicks submit so that the select and the datalists all update with the newly submitted record (and when you enter data in one div it populates the list in the other when you open it). right now i can get it to load the first time but once it loads the div it wont reload the div. I have put some of the source code below. I appreciate any suggestions!

-- the div rendered to the user (i have some jquery that opens it so ignore the display:none)

```
<div id="chkitemcntdiv" style="display:none; position: absolute; background-color: whitesmoke; padding: 2% 9% 4% 9%; z-index: 99; top: 26%; left: 40%; border: solid;">
    <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="chkitemcntonlyclosebtn" style="border:solid; border-style: outset;position: absolute; top: 2%; left: 92%;"> x </button><br /><br /><br />
    <form id="chkitemcntform">
        <div id="chkitemcntdivcontent">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Checkout Item(s) </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

-- load the form div content

```
$('#chkitemcntonlybtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/invman/invman_main_ajax.php?ajaxdiv=chkitemcntdiv",
        success: 
        function (data) {
            $('#chkitemcntdivcontent').html(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("A page control error has occurred. Please contact your systems administrator.");
        }
    });
});
```

-- the php that populates the form

```
IF ($_GET['ajaxdiv'] == 'chkitemcntdiv'){

    echo'   <div class="box-header">
                <b class="pull-center">Check Out Count Only Non-Trackable Item</b><br /> <br /> 
            </div>
            <label for="source">Source</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="source" id="source">';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM invman.locations where status = 1 and type in (SELECT loctype FROM invman.location_logic where logitem = 7 and location_logic.status = 1);";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                    
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['lid'].'">'.$row['description'].'</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<option> Error</option>";
                }
    echo'   </select><br />
            <label for="destination">Destination</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="destination" id="destination">';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM invman.locations where status = 1 and type in (SELECT loctype FROM invman.location_logic where logitem = 8 and location_logic.status = 1);";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['lid'].'">'.$row['description'].'</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<option> Error</option>";
                }
    echo'   </select><br />
            <label for="itemtype">Item Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="itemtype" id="itemtype">';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM invman.itemtypes where category = 2 and status = 1;";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['itemtypeid'].'">'.$row['itemtype'].'</option>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<option> Error</option>";
                }
    echo '  </select><br />
            <label for="count">Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="count" id="count" min="1"><br />';

}
```

-- the JQUERY form handler

```
$('#chkitemcntform').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/jsonsubmit/chkitemcnt.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $('#chkitemcntform').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#formreturn').html(data);
            $('#formreturn').slideToggle();
            $( '#chkitemcntform' ).each(function(){
                this.reset();
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#formreturn').fadeToggle(1500);
            }, 7000);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("There was an error checking out your count only item. Please contact your system administrator.");
        }
    });
});
```

-- the php handling the form submission.

```
if (!EMPTY($_POST)){
require("the connection string i have removed");
$cleandestination = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['destination']);
$cleansource = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['source']);
$cleanitemtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['itemtype']);
$cleanquantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['count']);
$transferid = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 200);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM invman.current_countonly_quantity_by_location where lid = '".$cleansource."' and itemtypeid = '".$cleanitemtype."';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    }
} else {
    exit('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">The quantity entered exceeds the quantity currently in inventory for the source. Please review source inventory or reduce your quantity.</div>');
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM invman.current_countonly_quantity_by_location where lid = '".$cleansource."' and itemtypeid = '".$cleanitemtype."' and quantity < '".$cleanquantity."';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        exit('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">The quantity entered exceeds the quantity currently in inventory for the source. Please review source inventory or reduce your quantity.</div>');
    }
} else {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO invman.cntitemslocations (itemtype, quantity_transfered, transferid, locid, movedate) VALUES ('".$cleanitemtype."','".$cleanquantity."','".$transferid."','".$cleandestination."', now());";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    } else {
        exit('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">A database error occurred updating your record. Please contact your systems administrator.</div>');
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO invman.cntitemslocations (itemtype, quantity_transfered, transferid, locid, movedate) VALUES ('".$cleanitemtype."',-'".$cleanquantity."','".$transferid."','".$cleansource."', now());";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">Item(s) checked out successfully.</div>';
    } else {
        exit('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">A database error occurred updating your record. Please contact your systems administrator.</div>');
    }
}

}
```

Hopefully this makes sense what I am trying to do. Lots of logic in my page but trying to keep it fresh, clean and user friendly for the front end user.